# Typescript react not importing correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following typescript:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

It produce the following js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const react_1 = require("react");
const react_dom_1 = require("react-dom");
const App = () => {
    return (react_1.default.createElement("div", null,
        react_1.default.createElement("p", null, "Hello world!")));
};
react_dom_1.default.render(react_1.default.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('app'));
//# sourceMappingURL=react.component.js.map
```

When running it, I get the following error:

> ```
> (index):29 Error: (SystemJS) Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined
> ```

It seems like `react_dom_1.default` is `undefined`, but I have no clue why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

### Update

> It worked. Could you maybe explain why the other method does not?

In the Es6 module system there are multiple ways to export and import:

#### Implicit import (AKA default)

You can export things like:

```
export default someVar;
```

And then import it as:

```
import someVar from "./somemodule"
```

#### Explicit import

You can export things like:

```
export { someVar };
```

And then import it as:

```
import { someVar } from "./somemodule";
```

A module can have multiple exports:

```
export { someVar1, someVar2 };
```

You can import multiple entities in one import:

```
import { someVar, someVar2 } from "./somemodule";
```

You can also declare aliases at entity level:

```
import { someVar as A, someVar2 as B } from "./somemodule";
```

Or at module level:

```
import * as SomeModule from "./somemodule";
```

Amd then access the entities:

```
console.log(SomeModule.someVar);
console.log(SomeModule.someVar2);
```

You were using the default import from React and ReactDom but those modules expose multiple entities.

Comment: It worked. Could you maybe explain why the other method does not?

Comment: In addition to that, if you only need the render method, you can do this:



```import { render } from 'react-dom'```

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react_dom_1.default.findDOMNode') Please help !